# Intellisense/Auto complete stops working on VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am using VS.NET 2008 with TFS Client installed. 
My solution is a big one, nearly 116 projects in it. 
It has been working fine, just that, from a week or so, it is behaving strange that it stops showing autocomplete/intellisense while I write code.

I first tried to close and re-open the solution and it didn't fixed that.
Reinstalled the SP to VS2008, it fixed for a while and then problem came again.
I removed all the VS2008 and TFS client and such things, and then re installed everything. worked great for a while but stopped working same day.

I wonder what I must do to make it work now. which should be permanent.

I was wondering if there is a cache of VS.NET (for each solution/project you are working on) and maybe clearing that cache may work. I am not sure.

Please note that if I open a new project or work on any other projects, it works fine. Its just that with one solution that auto complete is not working.

I also tried clean the solution, rebuild and whatever other things u can think of. Not sure why on this project only.

thanks for the help.
Sameers

Comment: I just tried to clear folder from **"C:\Users\Sameers\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation"** And it seems to fix again the issue. But I am not sure how long it will keep that working. Lets see.

Comment: Ok, It stopped working again. I am not sure what is the issue out there, but it works for a while and then stops working. It is weird that it do so all of a sudden. I am typing and all of a sudden, just like something broke, it stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, its been a while and it seems to be working.
I read somewhere on the internet, where someone suggested that you should try changing the location of your code. I did that, moved from existing drive to another drive. From that day, it seems to be working fine.

It does happen for a while that it does stop working, but then I just restart VS.NET and it works again.

I know its not a permanent solution, but yes, it worked for me.

Hope it may help for someone else too. Its too frustrated when you are used to have tea 10 times a day and suddenly they say, "tea can't be available to you anymore" :)

Sameers

Comment: Well, it is still coming back. It seems no one responding to this thread. It keeps coming back, I re-start visual studio, and sometimes it works, other times it doesn't. I restart windows and it seems to work again. I think it happens when there is too much memory used. I have 4GB on Windows7 x64. It seems the memory is not enough. But I wonder, I have been using it from years and it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (VS 2010):

```
Tools 
➔ Options 
➔ Text Editor 
➔ C/C++ 
➔ Advanced 
➔ Browsing/Navigation 
➔ Recreate Database 
➔ True
```

Then re-start Visual Studio.